# Incorrect HTML rendering

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, html-lists, rendering, thymeleaf

We are building a Spring Boot + Thymeleaf App, running on Tomcat 9 where an HTML page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea
                <ul>
                    <li>Black tea</li>
                    <li>Green tea</li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

is being rendered as :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea
                <ul>
                    </ul></li><li>Black tea</li>
                <li>Green tea</li>
                </ul>

        <li>Milk</li>


</body></html>
```

Please suggest as correct rendition of lists is needed for Bootstrap NavBar.

Comment: Is this a static html page that you're sending to the browser or is it being generated based on model attributes?

Comment: Could you please share the thymeleaf code?

Comment: The problem is occurring only when the page is being served dynamically via Thymeleaf templating engine. For testing we have this pain HTML only without any Thymleaf constructs.